# How can I use parameter I get through riot.route()?

Tags: javascript, riot.js

```
riot.route('/*', function(category) {
    riot.mount('#main', 'category-page', category)
})
```

When URL change, I want to get parameter as "category" and use it in `<category-page>`.
I tried `console.log(this.opts.category)`in `<category-page>`, but what I got is undefined.

```
riot.route('/*', function(category) {
    riot.mount('#main', 'category-page', category)
    console.log(category)
})
```

When I code like above, `console.log(category)` works well. So I think do wrong with passing or getting parameter. I tried many case but I couldn't resolve it.
Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to riot.js router api documentation when calling 
`riot.mount(selector, tagName, [opts])` you should pass an object that will be set to `this.opts` in your tag.

So your router code should look something like this:

```
riot.route('/*', function(category) {
    riot.mount('#main', 'category-page', {category: category})
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It work well. I checked document and I think it says  `riot.mount(selector, tagName, api)`. Anyway I really appreciate you!!